# JScript Runtime Error in ASP.net MVC 3 after placing the javascript in a separate JS File

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I've got this Javascript Runtime Error in ASP.net MVC3. The code fragment below works just fine but the problem here goes when I try to place the displayTime() into another .js file.... I tried placing the whole javascript function in a separate js file then adding another import like these:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/customFunction.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

right after the script Ive imported... all of this codes are placed in my _Layout.cshtml file. But unfortunate a MS JScript Runtime Error Occured in the `<body onload="displayTime()">` saying Object Expected.... :( Hope someone can help

```
<body onload="displayTime()">
        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function displayTime()
        {

        }
    </script>
    </body>
```

Here is the full code of the JS Function:

```
var serverTime = @DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
var serverOffset = serverTime - getClientTime();

function getClientTime()
{
    var time = new Date();

    return (time.getHours() * 60 * 60) +
        (time.getMinutes() * 60) + (time.getSeconds());
}

function displayTime()
{
    var serverTime = getClientTime() + serverOffset;
    var hours = Math.floor(serverTime / 60 / 60).toString();
    var minutes = Math.floor(serverTime / 60 % (hours * 60)).toString();
    var seconds = Math.floor(serverTime % 60).toString();

    hours = hours.length == 1 ? '0'+ hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes.length == 1 ? '0'+ minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds.length == 1 ? '0'+ seconds : seconds;

    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hours + ":" +
        minutes + ":" + seconds; // <-- updates the "clock" div.

    setTimeout(displayTime, 1000); // <-- calls this function again in 1 second.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var serverTime = @DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/customFunction.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body onload="displayTime()">
</body>
```

Comment: and, what did u do in the displayTime function? Did u referring anything in jQuery? If so, place all the script block in the <head> section

Comment: hi updated my question... putting my js function in a separate file... i didn't used any jquery

Comment: You can not use @ in the js file, cos @ only works in the cshtml file.So you can try moving the var serverTime = @DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds; into the cshtml file and remaining the other codes in the js file.

Comment: Awesome! It's working now... I learned something today :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The script containing this `displayTime` function should be placed in your `<head>` section. Alternatively since you are using jQuery, why don't you simply use the `$(document).ready` function?

Comment: Actually I did tried it.... but i just to make the most simplest thing to work first... and that is to resolve the Runtime Error... it's not finding the right location of the function placed in a separate js file... tried also placing the script in the head section but still no good